# Is it thread safe to iterate an array returned by Set.toArray()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a static `Set` which I am using to cache my `AType` instances. Multiple `Worker` instances will operate on different threads will. `Workers` will iterate this `Set`, performing operations based on properties of each `AType`.

(the properties of `AType` are never modified. Though the contents of the `Set` itself might be modified)

If I clone the `Set` to an Array in a thread safe manner, is it thread safe to then iterate that Array?

(I don't see why it wouldn't be. And it seems safe in the testing I did. But thread safety is hard to verify and it never hurts to ask...)

```
public class Worker {
  private AType[] reusableArray;

  private static Set<AType> theSet = new HashSet<>();

  public Worker() {
    //....
  }

  public void work() {
    //....

    doClone();

    for(AType aType : reusableArray) {
      // ...
    }
   }

  private void doClone() {
    synchronized (theSet) {
      //.. do stuff, maybe populate the set, maybe remove items from it.

      // try not to resize array unless necessary
      if(reusableArray == null || reusableArray.length() != theSet.size()) {
        reusableArray = new AType[theSet.size()];
      }

      theSet.toArray(reusableArray);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through all those hoops, just use a [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Alternatively, synchronized all access using [Collections.synchronizedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-).

Suggest first choice, but they each have their pros and cons.

Primarily, `ConcurrentHashMap` will *not lock* while querying the set (`contains()`, iteration, ...). Quoting javadoc:

> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do *not* entail locking.

---

**Note:** There is no `ConcurrentHashSet`. To get a `Set` create it like this:

```
private static Set<AType> theSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
                                     new ConcurrentHashMap<AType, Boolean>());
```

Voila! Fast, non-blocking `Set` that still allows multi-threaded access, both updating and querying.

Only caveat (quoting javadoc):

> For aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

Comment: If these Collections lock the object during iteration (which I assume they must, how else would they avoid Concurrent Modification issues?), then I lose all advantages of parellism, as most of the Workers time is spent performing the logic during iteration.

Comment: @ab11 As I already said, `ConcurrentHashMap` will not lock. Quoting javadoc: "However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do *not* entail locking". Read it yourself. It's why I supplied the link.

Comment: thanks, I read the link. Any idea how that works? What happens if the Collection is modified by another thread while being iterated? It probably iterates over a clone of the Collection? If so, how is this more efficient?

Comment: Read the source code if you want to know how they do it. Personally, I'm just happy someone really smart found a way to do it, and gave us the code. But no, it doesn't clone the *entire* map, and it's better than your code that does "clone" the set into an array every time `work` is called.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. One last thing, have you seen any documentation that states that newSetFromMap() will create a Concurrency safe set (if the parameter is a ConcurrentHashMap)? I looked through the source code, seems like it would have to be Concurrency safe because it is backed by the ConcurrentHashMap, but I don't see any documentation stating this is the case.

Comment: @ab11 Javadoc of [newSetFromMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-): "The resulting set displays the same ordering, **concurrency**, and performance characteristics as the backing map."

Answer (score 2):

`toArray` copies the contents of the set to the array. After it returns, the array and the set are completely unrelated.

After the first thread's call to `toArray` returns, you could modify the set in the same thread, you could modify the set in a different thread, you could let the set be garbage collected, or you could launch it to Jupiter. The first thread isn't using the set any more, and it couldn't care less what happens to it.

(Note that the references stored in the array are the same as the references stored in the set, so they refer to the same objects, and changing these objects could introduce thread safety problems. But you said you're not doing that)

Comment: This was my logic. (And also why I mentioned I'm not changing those objects, because I realize that would be an issue).

I guess my biggest concern was that the array's references might get garbage collected if the Set was emptied, though that seemed very unlikely as I have hard references to the arrays's contents... or just the persistent concern/caution that I'm missing something whenever writing multi-threaded stuff.

Comment: @ab11 You are right. The references can be garbage collected only after **both** the set and array goes out of scope.